# Xlib: How to ask window manager for maximized window size?

Tags: xlib, window-managers, x11

I want my program's window to be as big as possible without overlapping the window manager's various small windows e.g. the pager. Is there any way to ask the wm what the maximized window size is, before I create my window?

Answer (score 0):

`_NET_WORKAREA` property of the root window is probably closest match. However on a multi-headed system it will give you the combined work area on all monitors.

If that's what you want, fine (but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114738/how-to-make-x11-window-span-multiple-monitors/17118962#17118962) on making a window span multiple monitors). If you want to maximize over a single monitor, then there's a problem as there's no per-monitor API like `_NET_WORKAREA`. Your best bet is creating a window in a maximized state and then querying its size. If that's not an option, I'm afraid you will have to query the number and sizes of available monitors, and then go and calculate the work area of each monitor by subtracting "struts" from the full area (see [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) about `_NET_WM_STRUT` and `_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL`).

Comment: This is interesting, but neither wm that I use is providing valid values for _NET_WORKAREA. I use XFCE and I use twm.

Comment: So there's no way, then.

Comment: Isn't there a way for a program to query the root window to find out what windows exist on the screen and where they are? I should think if I had that info, it would be possible to find the largest rectangular area that is not occupied.

Comment: You can do that but you don't necessarily know which of those windows belong to the WM/desktop. In any case, instead of replicating some functions of a modern WM in your app, consider switching to a modern WM.