# Xlib - Get Desktop "Work Area"

Tags: c, x11, xlib

On windows, a monitor has a set work area defined by the available room on the desktop above the taskbar.  The simplest way of determining this is using the `SystemParametersInfo()` function with the `SPI_GETWORKAREA` flag.

Does something like this exist for X11?  An alternative definition of "work area" might be the resolution of a maximized window.

Comment: a must see answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124149/how-to-get-taskbar-size-and-position-with-python

Answer (score 2):

That's not a property of X11, which knows nothing about task bars and such. However, the [Extended Window Manager Hints](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.4/index.html) specification has something called `_NET_WORKAREA` property for the root window, see [this documentation text](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.4/ar01s03.html#idm139704063854592):

> [...] the current page minus space occupied by dock and panel windows [...]

That sounds about right.

Comment: What do I need to do to query this property?  I'm new to xlib in general.

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647983/xlib-how-to-ask-window-manager-for-maximized-window-size), though, which says that _NET_WORKAREA could report the combined area of all monitors, which I don't want.  That or it might not work at all.

Comment: Why would you need that? Just curious.

Comment: @n.m. I want to center the window in the working area.

Comment: For a single monitor _NET_WORKAREA works fine, but for multiple monitor configurations one needs to intersect it with a particular monitor rectangle. But even in that case it may not produce the correct work area, as some panels are present on some but not all monitors, and _NET_WORKAREA does not take that into account.