# Linux Window Manager Forces Window Size/Location

Tags: linux, qt, x11, gnome, xorg

We're using Red Hat Linux 6.4, and our application is built using Qt. The application has multiple windows and we support a layout system where our users can save the application layout and restore it later. The application is cross-platform, and on Windows, everything is fine. On Linux, we're having problems restoring windows when a window spans multiple monitors. Our configuration uses a single virtual X display spanning all monitors, and the users can manually position and size windows across the monitors as desired.

What we've found is that the window manager is enforcing a policy on windows that are programmatically set and forcing them not to span across divide between two monitors. When we attempt to restore a saved layout containing a window that spanned monitors, the window manager reduces its size and repositions at as it sees fit. Basically, as long as the user makes the change by dragging and resizing the window, the window manager respects it, but an application that programmatically sets it gets overridden. I'm sure someone somewhere thought this was a reasonable restriction, but our customers disagree.

A developer here has spent days searching and experimented trying to find a way to work around this behavior programmatically, or better yet, tell the window manager to stop doing that. We're using the GNOME desktop and Qt 4.8.x.

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Doug McGrath

Comment: See my answer to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114738/how-to-make-x11-window-span-multiple-monitors).