# Creating X11 window to span multiple displays

Tags: x11, monitor

I'm having the exact problem described here. [How to make X11 window span multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114738/how-to-make-x11-window-span-multiple-monitors)
I have six monitors and am trying to create a window larger than the size of one of the monitors.  It keeps getting resized by the window manager.
 Apologize if I should post within that thread, the etiquette is not clear to me.
Anhow, I do the following in my code:

```
 /* Pass some information along to the window manager to size the window */
  sizeHints.flags = USSize; //  | PMinSize;
  sizeHints.width = sizeHints.base_width = width; 
  sizeHints.height = sizeHints.base_height = height; 
  // sizeHints.min_width = width;
  // sizeHints.min_height = height;
  // sizeHints.max_width = mScreenWidth;
  // sizeHints.max_height = mScreenHeight;
  if (geometry->x != DONT_CARE && geometry->y != DONT_CARE) {
    sizeHints.x = geometry->x;
    sizeHints.y = geometry->y;
    sizeHints.flags |= USPosition;
  }

  XSetNormalHints(mDisplay, mWindow, &sizeHints);


  SetTitle(suggestedName); 
  XSetStandardProperties(mDisplay, mWindow, 
                         suggestedName.toAscii(), suggestedName.toAscii(), 
                             None, (char **)NULL, 0, &sizeHints);
  /* Bring it up; then wait for it to actually get here. */
  XMapWindow(mDisplay, mWindow);
```

The problem I'm having is that if I set min_width and min_height, the user cannot resize the window, which is not what I want.  But if I don't, then when I do any X11 call later, such as

```
  XGetWindowAttributes(mDisplay, mWindow, &win_attributes);
```

the window manager resizes my window to fit into one monitor instead of being larger than the monitor.  I cannot just get a window of the desired size for some reason.  Note that WidthOfScreen and HeightOfScreen give me the combined width and height of all monitors as expected.
Can anyone help?  I hope I'm explaining myself clearly enough.

Comment: What happens if you resize the window manually to span several monitors? Does WM resize it back?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  I can resize the window to as large as I want.  If I set the minimum size, I cannot make it smaller than the min_width and min_height.  If I don't set those, then while the user can drag the window larger, the program cannot resize the window to larger than a single display size.

Comment: I think you can set min height and width to span several monitors, map the window, then unset them. You want to use `xprop` to check window properties in its various states. You want it to have the same properties as after a manual resize.

Comment: How exactly do I "unset" them?  Would it be as simple as calling XSetNormalHints() without the PMinSize attribute in the flags?

Comment: PS I hate stackoverflow because it religiously refuses to inform me when someone replies to my thread.  Sorry for the delay in replying on my part due to this.

Comment: Yes, I think you unset them just like that. Or set them to some reasonable small values, like 10x10.

Comment: I'm going to try that soon.  Stay tuned

Comment: OK, so I tried the following:   [code] sizeHints.flags = USSize;
  XSetStandardProperties(mDisplay, mWindow, 
                         suggestedName.toAscii(), suggestedName.toAscii(), 
                         None, (char **)NULL, 0, &sizeHints); [/code]

Comment: OK, apparently I cannot use formatted text here, including simple carriage returns... Anyhow, after that code which hopefully you can read, I make a call to glXCreateContext and the window resizes to the wrong size. ... weird

Comment: No matter where I move the "don't enforce size minimums" code, from that point onward, anytime I do anything like glSwapBuffers or any window operation, the window manager seems to step in and resize the goddamn window to the size of one display.  How frustrating!  I have no idea why this is...

Comment: Well I think perhaps it's a WM bug, look at the source... I don't have a multi-monitor setup any more, but when I had one, I tested similar code and I don't think my WM behaved like that.

Comment: Hmm… yes, you are probably right.  This is the Gnome environment and I am going bats**t chasing it.  I put in a hacky fix for now and will definitely try to find the source code if I can.  Tahnks for your suggestions, very helpful to have someone to bounce ideas off of.

Comment: One last thing for future reference -- the actual "unsetting" of the preference consists of setting sizehints.min_width = sizehints.min_height = 0; with flags |= PMinSize