# XResizeWindow X11 Bigger then actual screen

Tags: c, user-interface, screen, x11

I am trying to resize an application windows. if my screen is, say 1500x600, and if I try to resize my app window to 1600 x 700, the function call resize it to 1500x600. 
How do I force it to exceed the screen size. This should be possible since I can resize the window by clicking the edge of the window and resizing it.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you resizing them? Which wm is used? It's up to wm what to do with resize requests

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114738/how-to-make-x11-window-span-multiple-monitors