# How to make a fixed position and size window in X11

Tags: x11

So I wanna make my window not moveable and resizable, is there anyway to do it? Below is my current window creation code.

```
testbwidgetptr->basewin = XCreateWindow(BOTIFDisplay,
                tmp->drawarea,
                testbwidgetptr->bwidgetx,
                testbwidgetptr->bwidgety,
                testbwidgetptr->bwidgetwidth,
                testbwidgetptr->bwidgetheight,
                0, CopyFromParent, InputOutput,
                CopyFromParent, valuemask, &winatt);
XSetWindowBackground(BOTIFDisplay, testbwidgetptr->basewin, WhiteDot);
```

Comment: You might want to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26848220/1793220

Answer (score 1):

> I wanna make my window not moveable and resizable

In X11 window management, the client doesn't get to define what they want. They can *ask* the window manager to do this or that (or not to do that), but in the end it is always up to the window manager. In fact, the specifications state clearly that the client application *must* deal with any size the window manager assigns to it – so the answer is: no, you cannot do that if you want your window to be managed.

As pointed out in a comment, you can set `override_redirect` on your window. This tells the window manager not to manage your window, which means that the window manager will not interfere with it. However, in theory any client could still resize your window (though this is extremely unlikely to happen).

However, you should be careful about this. Bypassing the window manager also means that you lose a lot of things: window decorations, focus handling and the like will all be gone. In particular, focus handling must be done by you.

To summarize, you should really consider whether `override_redirect` is actually what you want to use. In most cases, you should instead just build a client that can deal with arbitrary window sizes and positions.