# Create X11 Window with a fixed size

Tags: c++, linux, x11

For a C++ Vulkan application with X11, I need to create a window with a fixed size that cannot be maximized or scaled by the user. Reason is that the application is written for that size and just doesn't scale.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? A parameter to XCreateWindow maybe?

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a fixed position and size window in X11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191948/how-to-make-a-fixed-position-and-size-window-in-x11)

Comment: That did the trick but I just realized that my actual problem is a little different. I need to make sure that the visible area of the window stays the same size throughout the program. Currently it seems that the visible area is shrunk once the title bar and scrollbar is added and this changes the Vulkan surface size which causes my complications.